# Why the same code has different behaviors between main and junit test

Tags: java

I have a code snippets, the output are different when I use main and JUnit run it.

My question: why the output of these two ways is not the same?

I tried search on google, but no good answers. So asking here, hoping someone can explain.

```
// This output is true
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    Class<?> clazz = sun.security.ec.ECDHKeyAgreement.class;
    Class<?>[] empty = {};
    Constructor<?> con = clazz.getConstructor(empty);
    Object newInstance = con.newInstance();
    System.out.println(newInstance instanceof javax.crypto.KeyAgreementSpi);
}

// This output is false
@Test
public void test() throws Exception {
    Class<?> clazz = sun.security.ec.ECDHKeyAgreement.class;
    Class<?>[] empty = {};
    Constructor<?> con = clazz.getConstructor(empty);
    Object newInstance = con.newInstance();
    System.out.println(newInstance instanceof KeyAgreementSpi);
}
```

Comment: why don't you print out the actual class name and see why?

Comment: just guessing: besides the actual test method, Junit will also run @Before annotated method

Comment: In the second code snippet you are importing some class `KeyAgreementSpi`. It could be that the class you are importing is not `javax.crypto.KeyAgreementSpi` but for example `org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.asymmetric.dh.KeyAgreementSpi`. Replace `newInstance instanceof KeyAgreementSpi` with `newInstance instanceof javax.crypto.KeyAgreementSpi`.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem can be easily explained by importing a `KeyAgreementSpi` class different from `javax.crypto.KeyAgreementSpi`.

The following example requires the dependency "org.bouncycastle:pcprov-jdk15on" and prints "true" and "false":

```
import org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.asymmetric.dh.KeyAgreementSpi;

import java.lang.reflect.Constructor;

public class KeyAgreementTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        Class<?> clazz = sun.security.ec.ECDHKeyAgreement.class;
        Class<?>[] empty = {};
        Constructor<?> con = clazz.getConstructor(empty);
        Object newInstance = con.newInstance();
        System.out.println(newInstance instanceof javax.crypto.KeyAgreementSpi);
        System.out.println(newInstance instanceof KeyAgreementSpi);
    }
}
```